# Covering all legal/tax bases for sole proprietorship selling apps?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, sole-proprietorship

I'm just starting a sole proprietorship for making & selling iPhone/Android apps. I expect buyers all over USA/world.

As a traveling performer, my personal location is 50% Florida 50% California, maybe moving towards settling in California.

I want to register my business and open a business bank account. Here's what I think I need to do.

1. Establish a street address in Florida or California (plan to use UPS box, which provides a street address)
2. Run a week's worth of notifications in newspaper
3. Register Fictitious Name with state (DBA)
4. Register for an EIN with IRS
5. File a trademark application for business name

What am I missing? Even if I get a business mailing address in Florida but I sign a lease in California, do I need to declare the business in California? Do I need to declare it in every state?

How do I prepare to handle income from the app store?

Comment: This very much feels like something that should be on [Startups.SE](https://startups.stackexchange.com/).